# Query regarding placing the cursor position in empty text field

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield

i have registration page with text fields like user name,first name,password.when user clicks on submit button.if any field is empty i want to place the cursor position that text field,can any one help me out.

Comment: textField becomeFirstResponder;

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, It will look for any empty field in the parent view, and will assign focus to it

```
for(UIView* subView in [self.yourView subviews])
 {
    if([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField* textFeild = (UITextField*) subView;
        if([textFeild.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {

           [textFeild becomeFirstResponder];   ///Assign Focus
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this helped me @sarim sidd

Answer (score 2):

Find your text field object. And place this in your code.

```
if(textfieldobj.text.length == 0)
{
   [textfieldobj becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope this may help you...